# JQuery Datatable first time load issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

When I am trying to use JQuery datatable, for the first load, the datatable css is not loading properly,

but for subsequent loads, the table loads properly.

[image]

The following is the html

**HTML:**

```
<table id="test">
<thead id="testhead">
<tr> 
<th>Created Date </th>
<th>Source Name </th>
<th>Description </th>
</thead>
<tbody id="testbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

In Javascript, I am trying to create  and  dynamically and append it to $("testhead") and $("testbody") respectively.

```
                  dwr.util.removeAllRows("testhead");
                  dwr.util.removeAllRows("testbody");
                  var table_header = $("#testhead");
                  var header_row = $("<tr></tr>");

                  /**
                   *
                   * Populate table header
                   */
                  var cell = $("<th></th>");
                  cell.text("Created Date");
                  header_row.append(cell);

                  cell = $("<th></th>");
                  cell.text("Source Name");
                  header_row.append(cell);
                  table_header.append(header_row);

                  cell = $("<th></th>");
                  cell.text("Description");
                  header_row.append(cell);
                  table_header.append(header_row);

                  var table_body = $("#testbody");
                  for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                          var row = $("<tr></tr>");

                          var cell = $("<td></td>");
                          cell.text(data[i].createdDate.getDay() + "-" +
                          data[i].createdDate.getMonth() + "-" +
                          data[i].createdDate.getFullYear());
                          row.append(cell);

                          cell = $("<td></td>");
                          cell.text(data[i].sourceName);
                          row.append(cell);

                          cell = $("<td></td>");
                          cell.text(data[i].description);
                          row.append(cell);
                 }

              $('#test').dataTable({
                       "bJQueryUI":true,
                   "aLengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100,-1], [10,25,50,100,"All"]],
               "iDisplayLength" : 10,
               "bPaginate" :true,
               "bAutoWidth":true,
               "bRetrieve":true,
                              "aoColumns":[
                          {"sTitle":"Created Date","bSearchable" : true,"bSortable" :true},
                              {"sTitle":"Source Name","bSearchable" : true,"bSortable" :true},
                              {"sTitle":"Description","bSearchable" : true,"bSortable" :true},
               ],
               "sDom":'<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip><"clear">',
               "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
               "sPageButton":"paginate_button",
               "sPageButtonStaticDisbaled":"paginate_button"
               })

              $("#test").css("width","100%");
              $("#test").dataTable().fnDraw();

              showDiv('results');
```

In the first call to the function, my table is not getting rendered properly.

Could someone help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you show us your JavaScript?

Comment: @DerekHenderson I have added the javascript code

Comment: @DerekHenderson Could you please help?

Comment: There isn't enough for me to help with. Can you replicate this on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the issue from the html code being generated by javascript, could you post the html generated the first time when it didnt work and the second time when it worked so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and the solution that I have found is to override the default behavior by adjusting the width using css.

It is evident that on first load the width of datatable is `1320px`(in my case) and for the subsequent loads it is `1920px` which is the expected width.

Hence the simple solution is to include the below in your css:

```
.dataTable{
    width:1920px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps you guys too! :)